# Vehicle location tracer on android google maps

Tags: android, server

I am building an project which tracks vehicle location on android google maps. Vehicle will be using SIM 808 module to track the location and send it to server, but what to do next and how to do this task ?

Comment: Here is an example of doing this with PubNub: https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-05-12-broadcasting-realtime-location-data-for-android-live-updating-map/

Answer (score 1):

You have the option to implement one of the 2 methods :

- [Push Notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) with [Broadcast receivers](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) : Your server gets the current location and sends it to your phone through FCM (Firebase Cloud messaging), you're listening on your app for push notifications with the BroadCast Receiver and once a new location comes, you update the location marker on your map.
- [Long polling](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/) : which is simply a periodic HTTP request that you fire to your backend location service (every 10 seconds for example) and after each call you update the location marker on the map.

Comment: Just a technical point to be made: *long polling* is not firing an http request every 10 seconds. That is just polling. Long polling is opening an http connection and holding it open until there is something (a message) to respond with. After some time (say 5 minutes), if no message was sent, then the request is closed and reopened for another 5 minutes or until a message is sent (whichever happens first).